# Reading from TCP Server - When user sends the data twice

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have created TCP Client application and wanted to read and write to TCP server through my code. For reading from TCP Server I have created thread but it is not continuously firing the code of reading When I send the text from TCP server twice at the second time it gets fired and I am getting the data at the second time. Below is my code of reading and writing the data Please help me to resolve this

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;

namespace TCPClient
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int i;
        StreamWriter streamWriter;
        StreamReader streamReader;
        TcpClient client; // Creates a TCP Client
        NetworkStream stream; //Creats a NetworkStream (used for sending and receiving data)
        byte[] datalength = new byte[256]; // creates a new byte with length 4 ( used for receivng data's lenght)
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 747); //Trys to Connect
              ClientReceive(); //Starts Receiving When Connected
               // timer1.Enabled = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); // Error handler :D
            }
        }
        public void ClientReceive()
        {

            stream = client.GetStream(); //Gets The Stream of The Connection
            new Thread(() => // Thread (like Timer)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(stream.Read(datalength, 0, 256).ToString());
                while ((i = stream.Read(datalength, 0, 256)) != 0)//Keeps Trying to Receive the Size of the Message or Data
                {
                    // how to make a byte E.X byte[] examlpe = new byte[the size of the byte here] , i used BitConverter.ToInt32(datalength,0) cuz i received the length of the data in byte called datalength :D
                    // byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(1000); // Creates a Byte for the data to be Received On
                    byte[] data = new byte[1000];
                    stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length); //Receives The Real Data not the Size
                    this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate // To Write the Received data
                    {
                        txtLog.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "Server : " + Encoding.Default.GetString(data); // Encoding.Default.GetString(data); Converts Bytes Received to String
                    });
               }
            }).Start(); // Start the Thread
        }

        public void ClientSend(string msg)
        {
            stream = client.GetStream(); //Gets The Stream of The Connection
            byte[] data; // creates a new byte without mentioning the size of it cuz its a byte used for sending
            data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(msg); // put the msg in the byte ( it automaticly uses the size of the msg )
            int length = data.Length; // Gets the length of the byte data
            byte[] datalength = new byte[4]; // Creates a new byte with length of 4
            datalength = BitConverter.GetBytes(length); //put the length in a byte to send it
            stream.Write(datalength, 0, 4); // sends the data's length
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); //Sends the real data
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (client.Connected) // if the client is connected
            {
                ClientSend(textBox1.Text); // uses the Function ClientSend and the msg as txtSend.Text
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, TCP is a *stream* of *bytes*. It doesn't do any message framing. There's no guarantee that each call to `Send` at one end will be matched 1-1 with calls to `Receive` at the other end. So in `ClientReceive`, your first call to `Receive` with the 256 byte buffer may get anywhere from 1-256 bytes of data - so it may just get the length (if your lucky) or just part of the length, or the length + part of your message.

Comment: What I observed is While condition doesn't fires every time I gets fird only when server sends data 2nd time. Can you tell me how can I make it execute continously