# When I send a command to server from client , the client receives the response only if the request is sent twice

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, client

I am trying to send commands to the server , like for example requesting the server to send back the list of files in it's directory. The problem is that when I send the "list" command to the server, I have to send it twice in order for the server to send back the list of files to the client. I am sure that the server receives the command in both times as on the server side I print the result that is supposed to be sent to the client on the console and it appears both times.

I am using C# and TCPListeners to listen for incoming responses or commands, and TCPClient to send responses or commands between the server and the client.

The client code

```
    private TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(9090);
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("list");
        try
        {
            TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(serverIPFinal, 8080);
            if (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                NetworkStream networkStream = clientSocket.GetStream();
                networkStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
               // networkStream.Close();
               // clientSocket.Close();
                thdListener = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenerThreadList));
                thdListener.Start();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            isConnectedLbl.Text = "Server not running";
        }
    }
    //Listener Thread to receive list of files.
    public void listenerThreadList()
    {

        tcpListener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (handlerSocket.Connected)
            {
                Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                lock (this)
                {
                    if (handlerSocket != null)
                    {
                        nSockets.Add(handlerSocket);
                    }
                }
                ThreadStart thdstHandler = new
                ThreadStart(handlerThreadList);
                Thread thdHandler = new Thread(thdstHandler);
                thdHandler.Start();
            }
        }
    }
    //Handler Thread to receive list of files.
    public void handlerThreadList()
    {

        Socket handlerSocketList = (Socket)nSockets[nSockets.Count - 1];
        NetworkStream networkStreams = new NetworkStream(handlerSocketList);

        int requestRead = 0;
        string dataReceived;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        //int iRx = soc.Receive(buffer);
        requestRead = networkStreams.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
        char[] chars = new char[requestRead];

        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, requestRead, chars, 0);
        dataReceived = new System.String(chars);

        Console.WriteLine(dataReceived);
        MessageBox.Show(dataReceived);

        //tcpListener.Stop();
        thdListener.Abort();


    }
```

The Server code:

```
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(8080);        
    public void listenerThreadCommands()
    {

        tcpListener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();

            if (handlerSocket.Connected)
            {
                Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
                connections.Items.Add(
                handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " connected.");
                // clientIP = handlerSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                lock (this)
                {
                    nSockets.Add(handlerSocket);
                }
                ThreadStart thdstHandler = new
                ThreadStart(handlerThreadCommands);
                Thread thdHandler = new Thread(thdstHandler);
                thdHandler.Start();
                //tcpListener.Stop();


                //handlerSocket.Close();
            }
        }

    }
    //Handler Thread to receive commands
    public void handlerThreadCommands()
    {
        Socket handlerSocketCommands = (Socket)nSockets[nSockets.Count - 1];

        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(handlerSocketCommands);

        int requestRead = 0;
        string dataReceived;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        requestRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1024);
        char[] chars = new char[requestRead];

        System.Text.Decoder d = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
        int charLen = d.GetChars(buffer, 0, requestRead, chars, 0);
        dataReceived = new System.String(chars);

        //connections.Items.Add(dataReceived);
        if (dataReceived.Equals("list"))
        {
            localDate = DateTime.Now;

            Files = Directory.GetFiles(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                                 .Select(Path.GetFileName)
                                 .ToArray();
            String FilesString = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
            {
                FilesString += Files[i] + "\n";
            }
            String clientIP = handlerSocketCommands.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            int index = clientIP.IndexOf(":");
            clientIP = clientIP.Substring(0, index);
            WriteLogFile(logFilePath, clientIP, localDate.ToString(), " ", "list");
            Console.WriteLine(clientIP);
            Console.WriteLine(FilesString);

            Byte[] bytesToSend = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(FilesString);

            try
            {
                WriteLogFile(logFilePath, clientIP, localDate.ToString(), " ", "list-response");

                TcpClient clientSocket = new TcpClient(clientIP, 9090);
                if (clientSocket.Connected)
                {

                    NetworkStream networkStreamS = clientSocket.GetStream();
                    networkStreamS.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);
                    networkStreamS.Close();
                    clientSocket.Close();
                    networkStream.Close();
                    //tcpListener.Stop();

                    // handlerSocketAuthenticate.Close();

                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Cant send");
            }
        }

        else if (dataReceived.Equals("downloadfile"))
        {
            // handlerSocketAuthenticate.Close();
            // tcpListener.Stop();
            networkStream.Close();
            thdListenerDownload = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listenerThreadDownloading));
            thdListenerDownload.Start();
        }

        else
        {
            String clientIP1 = handlerSocketCommands.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            int index = clientIP1.IndexOf(":");
            clientIP1 = clientIP1.Substring(0, index);
            // handlerSocketAuthenticate.Close();
            CommandExecutor(dataReceived, clientIP1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you can't give us enough code to figure out what the problem is, all we can offer you is sympathy. I'm not saying we *will*. But it's at least a possibility.

Comment: Unless you add the code for the client and the server nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from TCP Server - When user sends the data twice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35174983/11683)

Comment: @Gusman here I added it sorry I haven't noticed that I haven't pasted the code

Comment: @GSerg I can't find an answer in that thread

Comment: You are connecting a socket on the client and then you are doing `tcpListener.AcceptSocket();` again on the client.  This is a complete mess. Throw it all away and start from scratch.  There are plenty of good examples on the interwebz, there is no need to untangle this hopeless mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so many different things wrong with the code you posted, it's hard to know where to start, and it's impossible to have confidence that in the context of a Stack Overflow, one could sufficiently address all of the deficiencies. That said, in the interest of helping, it seems worth a try:

1. Sockets are bi-directional. There is no need for the client to use `TcpListener` at all. (By convention, the "server" is the endpoint that "listens" for new connections, and the "client" is the endpoint that initiates new connections, by connecting to a listening server.)
   You should just make a single connection from client to server, and then use that socket both for sending to and receiving from the server.
2. You are setting the `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` property to `false`. This is evil. The exceptions that occur are there to *help* you. Setting that property to `false` disables the exceptions, but does *nothing* to prevent the problems that the exceptions are designed to warn you about.
   You should use some mechanism to make sure that when you access UI objects, you do so only in the thread that owns those objects. The most primitive approach to this is to use `Control.Invoke()`. In modern C#, you are better off using `async`/`await`. With `TcpClient`, this is easy: you already are using `GetStream()` to get the `NetworkStream` object that represents the socket, so just use the asynchronous methods on that object, such as `ReadAsync()`, or if you wrap the stream in a `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader`, use the asynchronous methods on *that* object, such as `ReadLineAsync()`.
3. You are checking the `Connected` property of the `TcpClient` object. This is pointless. When the `Connect()` method returns, you are connected. If you weren't, an exception would have been thrown.
4. You are not sufficiently synchronizing access to your `nSockets` object. In particular, you use its indexer in the `handlerThreadList()` method. This is safe when using the object concurrently only if you have guaranteed that no other thread is modifying the object, which is not the case in your code.
5. You are writing to the stream using ASCII encoding, but reading using UTF8 encoding. In practice, this is not really a problem, because ASCII includes only the code points 0-127, and those map exactly to the same character code points in UTF8. But it's *really* bad form. Pick one encoding, stick with it.
6. You are accepting using `AcceptSocket()`, but then just wrapping that in a `NetworkStream` anyway. Why not just use `AcceptTcpClient()` and call `GetStream()` on that? Both `Socket` and `TcpClient` are fine APIs, but it's a bit weird to mix and match in the same program, and will likely lead to some confusion later on, trying to keep straight which you're using where and why.
7. Your code assumes that the `handlerThreadCommands()` method will always be called in exactly the same order in which connections are accepted. That is, you retrieve the current socket with `nSockets[nSockets.Count - 1]`. But, due to the way Windows thread scheduling works, it is entirely possible that two or more connections could be accepted before any one of the threads meant to handle the connection is started, with the result that only the most recent connection is handled, and it is handled by those multiple threads.
8. You are assuming that command strings will be received as complete units. But this isn't how TCP works. TCP guarantees only that if you receive a byte, it will be in order relative to all the bytes sent before it. But you can receive any number of bytes. In particular, you can receive just a single byte, or you can receive multiple commands concatenated with each other, or you can receive half a command string, then the other half later, or the second half of one command and the first half of the next, etc. In practice, these problems don't show up in early testing because the server isn't operating under load, but later on they very well may be. And the code needs to be designed from the outset to work properly under these conditions; trying to patch bad code later is much more difficult.

I can't say that's the above are the only things wrong with the code, but they are most glaring, and in any case I think the above is sufficient food for thought for you at the moment.

Bottom line: you really should spend more time looking at *good* networking examples, and really getting to understand how they work and why they are written the way they do. You'll need to develop a good mental model for yourself of how the TCP protocol works, and make sure you are being very careful to follow the rules.

One resource I recommend highly is [The Winsock Programmer's FAQ](http://tangentsoft.net/wskfaq/). It was written long ago, for a pre-.NET audience, but most of the information contained within is still very much relevant when using the higher-level networking APIs.

Alternatively, don't try to write low-level networking code yourself. There are a number of higher-level APIs that use various serialization techniques to encode whole objects and handle all of the lower-level network transport mechanics for you, allowing you to concentrate on the value-added features in your own program, instead of trying to reinvent the wheel.